# Lyapunov Stability is a problem for me

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let be $ \dot{X} = F(X) $, $F \in C^1( \mathbb{R}^n)$, $P \in \mathbb{R}^n$ isolate singular point. Suppose there exists a family $S_{{r}_i}$ with $ i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$S_{{r}_i} = \left \lbrace X \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\colon  |\!| X - P|\!| = r_{i} \right \rbrace$ , where $r_{i} \to 0$ when $i \to \infty$

such that the flow intersects transversely to each $S_{{r}_i}$. What can I say about Lyapunov Stability - asymptotically stability of $P$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: consider function $f(X) = \vert\!\vert X - P \vert\!\vert^2$ in some small neighbourhood of point $P$. If $\gamma(t)$ is a solution that starts in this neighbourhood, what could you say about derivative $\frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t))$ (use the transversality condition)?

Comment: This is for apply Liapunov theorem?

Comment: Exactly. Here we can use the simplest theorem about Lyapunov stability.

Comment: But, in the case that $\frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t)) < 0$ I have an idea, but what is about case $\frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t)) > 0$?.

Comment: The latter case gives you a result of system asymptotic Lyapunov stability in backward time. In forward time you may say that every solution that starts in some ball leaves that ball and never comes back again, so steady state is not even Lyapunov stable.